# Printing BITMAP using TSPL in Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, bitmap, tspl

I'm trying to print BITMAP using TSPL in Flutter. The manual says, BITMAP command should be used like that:

```
BITMAP x,y,width,height,mode,bitmap data
```

In Flutter, I'm encoding the image like that:

```
    var f = (await rootBundle.load("lib/assets/yerli.bmp")).buffer.asUint8List();

    var str = hex.encode(f);

    String bytes = "SIZE 60 mm, 40 mm\nGAP 2 mm\nSET CUTTER 1\nCLS\nCODEPAGE 1254\nBITMAP 100,100,100,100,0,\"$str\"\"\nPRINT 1\n";
```

Output of str variable is below

```
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
```

It can be copied to an online hexadecimal to image converter and can be seen it is valid. It generates an image.

But my printer does not see it as an image and it only prints characters.

Can anyone explain me how BITMAP command works? And how to convert BITMAP asset to bytes in order to send properly to mobile printer?

Comment: did you find the solution, I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Sorry, I could not find it. @Tim